# how to call a base class method by super keyword

Tags: java

```
class base
{
    public void superMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello i m a super class method");
    }
}

class der extends base
{
    super.superMethod();// error identifier expected 
}
```

i need to call a base class method without overloading it into derive class please provide me solution for it

Comment: Indent your code with 4 spaces to make it understandable.

Comment: Your error "identifier expected" is caused by you calling a method at the class level. This only works if the method returns something and you are assigning it to an instance variable, hence why it's expected an identifier for an instance variable.

Comment: y i cannot call the super methods and variables at class level

Comment: Because in java you can write statements only in blocks, it can be block, init block, const, method . not at place you are trying to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to do anything apart from calling the method. You do need to be inside a instance method, constructor or a instance initializer block to do that though. You only need the super keyword if you have to make a distinction when you are overriding the method.

```
class Base
{
 public void superMethod()
 {
  System.out.println("Hello i m a super class method");
 }
}
class Der extends base
{
  public void method()
  {
     superMethod();// error identifier expected 
  }

  public void superMethod()
  {
     super.superMethod()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't put code inside a method. The following should work:

```
class base {
    public void superMethod() {
        System.out.println("Hello i m a super class method");
    }
}

class der extends base {
    public void someMethod() {
        super.superMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited your post for you. To display a block of code it needs to be indented 4 spaces. This can easily be done by highlighting the code and pressing `Ctrl+k`

Comment: Thanks! :) (still a newbe here..)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything special.  Just call the method in the base class.  Since you have not overloaded it, it will automatically call the base class method.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the super class method following the below example.

```
class base
{
    public void superMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("hello i m a super class method");
    }
}

class der extends base
{
    {
        super.superMethod();
    }
}

class Supertest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new der();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class base{
    public void superMethod(){
        System.out.println("hello i am super class method");
    }
}
class der extends base{
    void supermethod(){
        super.superMethod();
        System.out.println("hello this is der class");
    }
}
class mainclass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        der r=new der();
        r.supermethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution. However, just posting code without any explanation is not a good style on Stack Overflow. Could you please add one or two lines of explanation? For example, because your answer looks similar to other answers, what kind of added value does your answer provide?