# how do you call a overridden super-class method directly from subclass

Tags: java, oop

```
class a{
  public void foo(int a){
     System.out.println("super");
  }
}
class b extends a{
  public void foo(int a){
     System.out.println("sub");
  }
}
```

And this is how I wrote my code to call it

```
a ob = new b(); 
ob.foo(7);
```

but it calls the subclass method ?

Comment: It is what overriding for. The overridden method shall not be accessible from outside of the classes at all. But you can call it within the child class itself.

Comment: to call a `super` class method from `within` a sub class you can use the `super` keyword.

Comment: Probable duplicate: [how to call a base class method by super keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595858/how-to-call-a-base-class-method-by-super-keyword)

Comment: are you guys really sure that there is no other method to get around this problem ?

Comment: AFAIK theres no way to disable `polymorphism` in java, its inherent to the language as well as the JVM, its one of the pinacles of java, it relies heavily on it.

Comment: Why? All I can gather from this is that you overrode the method but you didn't know what the resulting behaviour would be. So why *did* you override it? And why do you consider this to be a 'problem' that you need to 'get around'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ... but it calls the subclass method

That's the WHOLE POINT of overriding ... so that when you call the method on an instance the subclass you get the subclasses override of the method!

On the other hand, *the subclass itself* can call the overridden version of the method in its superclass:

```
class A {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("super");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public void foo() {
        super.foo();  // call the overridden method
        System.out.println("sub");
    }
}
```

... which will print

```
super
sub
```

if you call `foo` on a `B` instance.

---

> are you guys really sure that there is no other method to get around this problem ?

1. Yes
2. I don't see why you think it is a "problem".